# linux dirty_writeback_centisecs kernel parameter has no effect

Tags: linux, parameters, kernel

Today, I am learning the linux filesystem. I learned about the `.dirty` kernel paramter. When I want to test the `dirty_writeback_centisecs` parameter, I find the `dirty_writeback_centisecs` has no effect.

I set the `dirty_writeback_centisecs` kernel parameter to the value 5000.

In theory, the dirty data in memory may be flush to the disk. But I open a file `hello` with Python, then write "hello world" to the memory with the file handle. I wait 500 seconds, the file `hello` is still empty.

Before the test, the file `hello` is empty:

```
linux-4gcq:/tmp # cat hello
linux-4gcq:/tmp #
```

use the python to write file:

```
f = open('/tmp/hello','w')
f.write('hello world')
```

I wait a long time, but the file is still empty.

Comment: Have you tried closing the file? `f.close()`

Answer (score 1):

Python buffers output with `f.write`.  You need to use `f.flush`.

Nothing to do with the kernel parameters.  You'd see the file contents regardless of those kernel parameters, they only affect when something gets to the media, not when you see it in the filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.html

it seems `dirty_writeback_centisecs` is for setting the period for dirty check to see if anything needs to be flushed. you probably also need to set `dirty_expire_centisecs` so that old data that meet the criteria get flushed out